# CruiseControl Fail

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I have a batch file that is running inside CruiseControl and outputing either "Pass" or "Fail". How can I manage CruiseContorl so that the build fails if the output of my batch file is "Fail"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the return value of the batch file is non-zero, the build will report as having failed.

Comment: In other words, "exit 1". :-P

Answer (score 1):

in your ant script use the *failonerror* flag:

```
<exec executable="xxx" failonerror="true">
```

The executable (script) needs to signal failure by setting an non zero return code (call to exit)